# Word online and Word XML

Tags: xml, ms-word, openxml, office-js

Is it possible to access the underlying XML from a task pane app on Word online? I am able to use functions like `getNamesoaceAsync` or `getXmlAsync` in the desktop Word but the online Word always throws error code 6000 - no such node found.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.  [`CustomXmlPart.getXmlAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161103.aspx) and [`CustomXmlPrefixMappings.getNamespaceAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142271.aspx) are not available in Office Online (in browser).

However, other calls are available such as [`Document.getSelectedDataAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142294.aspx), which can be called with a `coercionType` of `Office.CoercionType.Ooxml` to retrieve OOXML.

Comment: @Suman Further to kjhughes answer: The syntax suggested works for both Word 2013 and 2016. Since Word online uses the JS APIs for Word 2016, there are additional methods that can be used to get the underlying WordOpenXML, and you can get it for specific parts of the document, for example from the Body or a Range, using getOoxml. See for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt616492.aspx